R Markdown two tables in one line
I want to place two tables inline in RMD file. Code as bellow produces only one table.
---
title: "2_test_RMD"
output: blastula::blastula_email
date: "2024-09-26"
---

```{r include=FALSE}
library(gt)
```



`r gt(head(mtcars)) ;gt(head(mtcars)) `

I want rmd file to show to tables in one line (not one under the other).

Do you have an example of how you want to display them? Do the tables have the same columns name and could be rbinded? Did you try displaying them in two different chunks, one after the other one?

I tried to display tables in two different chunks but they are displayed not inline but one after other.

Is it possible to rbind the tables and display one table? You could use pack_rows to differentiate tables

At the markdown level, you could try a multicolumn layout.

R markdown has some different ways to go about it. Here is from the Rmarkdown cookbook. Might have to include some HTML/CSS to get some space
---
title: "2_test_RMD"
output: html_document
date: "2024-09-26"
---


:::: {style="display: flex;"}
::: {}
```{r include = FALSE}
library(gt)
```
```{r }
gt(head(mtcars))
```
:::
::: {} 
```{r}
gt(head(mtcars))
```
:::
::::


